# Is the set path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness, path-connected

I want to check if the following set is connected, and path-connected.

A set can be path-connected only if it is connected, or not?

$$\displaystyle{D=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1  \text{ or }  x_2\in \mathbb{Q}\}}$$

The set is equivalent to $\displaystyle{\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Q}}$.

The set of rational numbers is not connected, since it ban be written as a union of two non-empty sets: $\mathbb{Q} = ((-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q})\cup((\sqrt{2}, \infty)\cap\mathbb{Q})$.

From that we get that neither the set $D$ is connected, also that implies that $D$ is not path-connected, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D is path connected because it is a collection of verticle lines criss crossing a collection of horizonal lines.
It is like a screen with a very tiny mesh or graph paper with infinitesmial squares

Comment: So, is $D$ also connected? So is what I have done for $D$ wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar It is also connected. The point where you are wrong is that a connected set (by defintion) cannot be written as union of two nonempty open and **disjoint** subsets. Note that $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Q}$ are not disjoint.

Comment: Oh I meant to write the set of rational numbers as $\mathbb{Q} = ((-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q})\cup((\sqrt{2}, \infty)\cap\mathbb{Q})$. Isn't this an union of disjoint sets?

Comment: @MaryStar Your example is correct: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not connected. But $D$ is. Consider simplier case: $X=\{0, 1\}$ is not connected (two points) but $X\times\mathbb{R}\cup\mathbb{R}\times X$ is (four crossing lines). Try drawing it to see what's happening.

Comment: So, at D to connect the points we need vertical and horizontal lines. To show that $D$ is path-connected can we just bescribe it in that way, or can we also define a map that bescribes a path between two points?

Comment: @MaryStar.  No, the graph is just a picture that helps you see where to go.  You have to describe a path from one point to another.  There few different cases depending upon where the points are.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-)